# WordPress removing original image after resize?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, function, unlink

In wordpress media library is there any way to remove original image after a resize? It seems to keep the original and I feel this wastes a lot of space.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-sizes/

Comment: Hi @Jonny Jordan did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` filter to manipulate upload image.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'txt_domain_delete_fullsize_image');

function txt_domain_delete_fullsize_image($metadata)
{
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $full_image_path = trailingslashit($upload_dir['basedir']) . $metadata['file'];
    $deleted = unlink($full_image_path);

    return $metadata;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.
**The code is tested and fully functional.**
Hope this helps!

Comment: The image is not displayed in the featured image, when you create the post

Comment: the code deletes -scaled.jpg but not the biggest one (original)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the direct answer to this and it's a good idea to keep the original image for internal wordpress plugins.

However one way you can reduce the storage and reduce cost is to use the AWS S3 Plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/
This will require you to first setup an AWS S3 Bucket.
Feel free to ask another question related to doing that if it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Works Wordpress 5.6
This one does show the featured image

```
function replace_uploaded_image($image_data) {
      // if there is no large image : return
  if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['large'])) return $image_data;

  // paths to the uploaded image and the large image
  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$image_data['file'];
  // $large_image_location = $upload_dir['path'] . '/'.$image_data['sizes']['large']['file']; // ** This only works for new image uploads - fixed for older images below.
  $current_subdir = substr($image_data['file'],0,strrpos($image_data['file'],"/"));
  $large_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/'.$current_subdir.'/'.$image_data['sizes']['large']['file'];

  // delete the uploaded image
  unlink($uploaded_image_location);

  // rename the large image
  rename($large_image_location,$uploaded_image_location);

  // update image metadata and return them
  $image_data['width'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['width'];
  $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['height'];
  unset($image_data['sizes']['large']);

  return $image_data;
}

add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','replace_uploaded_image');
```